# Specializing an implementation of inner class

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to specialize `Outer<P>::Inner` on the type `P` as shown below and it appears to work (on gcc 4.5.3 and Visual Studio 2008), until a member variable `Inner i` is declared in `Outer<P>`. Is it there a way to declare `Inner i` without specializing `Outer<P>`?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct Outer
{
    Outer()
    {
        Inner();
    }

    struct Inner;   
    //Inner i;      // compilation error
};

template<>
struct Outer<bool>::Inner
{
    Inner()
    {
        std::cout << "Specialization ..." << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
struct Outer<T>::Inner
{
    Inner()
    {
        std::cout << "Generic version ..." << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Outer<char> o2;
    Outer<bool> o1;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making `i` a (shared) pointer seems to work

```
template<typename T>
struct Outer
{
    Outer() : i( new Inner() )
    {
    }

    struct Inner;   
    boost::shared_ptr<Inner> i;
};
```

Here's what I think is going on. In the original code `Inner` is declared after `Outer`, as it should. Therefore the size of `i` is not known when it is declared. In the above snippet `i` is a pointer and its size is known even though `Inner` is yet to be defined.

Specializing `Inner` inside `Outer`, before declaring `i`, "works" in Visual Studio 2008 but fails in gcc 4.5.3, as it should, because the standard forbids it.

However the standard allows partial specialization in class scope. This makes it possible to have a non-pointer member `i` albeit templated on a a dummy parameter `T2=T1`, as shown below, although I think I'll go with the (smart) pointer version.

```
template<typename T1>
struct Outer
{
    template<typename T2,bool>
    struct Inner; 

    template<typename T2>
    struct Inner<T2,true>
    {
        Inner()
        {
            std::cout << "# Specialization ..." << std::endl;
        }
    };

    template<typename T2>
    struct Inner<T2,false>
    {
        Inner()
        {
            std::cout << "# Generic version ..." << std::endl;
        }
    };  

    Outer()
    {
    }

    Inner<T1,boost::is_same<T1, bool>::value> i;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Specialisations have to be done at namespace level. So the easiest way to do this is declaring `Inner` at namespace level:

```
template <typename T>
struct Outer_Inner
{
  Outer_Inner()
  {
    std::cout << "Generic version ..." << std::endl;
  }
};

template <>
struct Outer_Inner<bool>
{
  Outer_Inner()
  {
    std::cout << "Specialization ..." << std::endl;
  }
};


template<typename T>
struct Outer
{
  Outer() : i()
  {
  }

  Outer_Inner<T> i;      // no error anymore
};
```

In C++11 there's a workaround to get everything defined inside the class, but I wouldn't recommend it.

```
template<typename T>
struct Outer
{
  Outer() : i()
  {
  }

  struct generic_inner
  {
    generic_inner()
    {
      std::cout << "Generic version ..." << std::endl;
    }
  };

  struct special_inner
  {
    special_inner()
    {
      std::cout << "Specialization ..." << std::endl;
    }
  };

  typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, bool>::value,
                            special_inner, generic_inner>::type i;
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping to have the inner class `Inner` access the members of `Outer<T>`, without using the `friend` keyword.

Comment: @Olumide: What is the *problem* with the `friend` keyword? Whether it is an inner type or a `friend`, the coupling is just as tight.